# Laravel string Localization in config files

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm having problem using trans() function in config file, I feel it not supposed to be used that way. However I've no clue on what would be the most efficient way to translate string text in config files (files in /config folder).

Original code

```
<?php

return [
    'daily' => 'Daily'
];
```

When I try to implement trans() application crashes and laravel return white page without any error messages

```
<?php

return [
    'daily' => trans('app.daily_text')
];
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having the same problem but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The config files are one of the first stuff Laravel initialize, it means you can't use `Translator` nor `UrlGenerator` inside a config file.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but you shouldn't need to use `Translator` inside a config file though...

Answer (score 5):

You cannot not use trans or route method inside the Laravel config file. At the time the config file is loaded, these methods are not available to run. Also, the purpose of the configuration file is used for storing pure value and we should not trigger any actions inside the configuration file.

I know sometimes you want to put things into config file with dynamic data generated from route or text from language key. In my usecase is: configure the menu structure inside the config file. On that case, you should choose the approach of: storing only the translation key and an array which include information that you can generate the URL at run time.

I put my [gist](https://gist.github.com/khoatran/5467624c07002d3274d0) here for you to look up on the approach.

Answer (score 4):

You can just store the key in config file like and then use the trans function in the view to get the translations:

Config file:

```
<?php

return [
'foo' => 'bar'

];
```

Then in the view:

```
{{ trans(config('config.foo') }}
```

Comment: Right. So obvious solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is good practice but I ended doing this in my similar situation.

Config.php:

```
'Foo' => array('
'route' => 'route.name',
'name' => 'translated_line', //translated in lang file ex. /en/general.php
'),
```

Then in the view I used:

```
<a href="{{ route(Config::get('foo.route')) }}">{{ Lang::get('general.'.Config::get('foo.name'))) }}</a>
```

Maybe this is too late but I posted it here anyway so that maybe someone will find it useful, like me :))

Answer (score 2):

As of [Laravel v5.4, you can use the `__` helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization#retrieving-translation-strings) to access the translations after Laravel has booted.

Example:

> config/example.php

```
<?php

return [
    'daily' => 'Daily',
    'monthly' => 'app.monthly_text',
    'yearly' => 'app.yearly_text'
];
```

> resources/lang/en/app.php

```
<?php

return [
    'monthly_text' => 'Monthly'
];
```

You can access the translations like so:

```
<?php

// ...

$daily = config('example.daily');
$a = __($daily); // "Daily"

$monthly = config('example.monthly');
$b = __($monthly); // "Monthly"

$yearly = config('example.yearly');
$c = __($yearly); // "app.yearly_text"
```

Comment: The OP was not asking for that. He was trying to call trans() / __() in a config file.